# How to loop through object and insert into SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I'm using `VB.NET` AND `SQL SERVER 2008`

I've  Array of object that I need to `INSERT` into `SQL SERVER 2008` this is the object [image]

this object will be `Inserted` in to three tables :

- First table will have the report information : [ id ,reportName , description , style ] after inserting this information i'll use the `@@IDENTITY` of this `Row` as `FK` for the second Table
- SECOND table : [id , id_first_table, comment,complete,finished,name,started,outcome]

**Question** will come with the third table 
How can i loop through the checklist `Element` and inserting it to the third table using the second table id till the end of element

like :

```
 [id , id_second_table, 101 ,820] 
 [id , id_second_table'sameid', 101,831]
```

Here is what i have tried  :

```
 DECLARE @reportId INT , @fieldId INT  

 INSERT INTO    
 dbo.tblReport(strReportName,strReportDescription,strReportStyle,
 strScource,dtmCreated)
 VALUES ('caustic' , 'titration caustic', 'simple table' ,'user' ,  getdate()) 
 SELECT @reportId = @@IDENTITY

 INSERT INTO dbo.tblReportFields   
 (lngReports,strFieldName,bolComment,bolComplete,bolFinished,
 bolOutCome,bolStarted,bolUser)
 VALUES (@reportId ,'caustic titration' , 1,0,1,0,0,0)
 SELECT @fieldId = @@IDENTITY 

 --LOOP AND INSERT ALL THE checklist Element 

  INSERT INTO dbo.tblReportTask (lngReportFields,lngChecklist,lngTask)
  VALUES (@fieldId, 814 , 1443)
```

any ideas on the best way of doing this will be also considered

Comment: What is your VB.NET code to insert the records?

Comment: i don't have any ideas yet , so far i found the best way of doing this is to conver this object to data table

Comment: So, you have this object in code but have no code to get it into the database, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, your info was a little hard to work with since your Object and SQL Statements don't quite match up.  However, here is basically how you do it.  I hope you can relate it back to your problem.

This is how you insert the Report and ReportFields tables.  I didn't include the SQL for the ReportFields table since it is similar to the Report one.

```
  Dim reportID As Integer = 0
  Dim fieldID As Integer = 0
  Using tmpCONN As New SqlConnection(tmpConnStr)
    Dim tmpSQL As New StringBuilder
    tmpSQL.AppendLine("INSERT INTO dbo.tblReport(strReportName,strReportDescription,strReportStyle,strScource,dtmCreated) ")
    tmpSQL.AppendLine(" VALUES ")
    tmpSQL.AppendLine("(@NAME, @DESC, @STYLE, @SOURCE,@CREATED); ")
    tmpSQL.AppendLine("SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ScopeID; ")
    Using tmpCMD As New SqlCommand(tmpSQL.ToString, tmpCONN)
      tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", Obj.Name)
      tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DESC", Obj.Description)
      tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STYLE", Obj.Stype)
      tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOURCE", Obj.Source)
      tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATED", Date.Now)
      reportID = tmpCMD.ExecuteScalar
    End Using

    'Do same type of insert here for the ReportFields table.  Instead of reportID,'
    'it would return fieldID.'


    'This is the loop to insert to Tasks'
    For Each chk As chkObj In Obj.Checklist
      tmpSQL = New StringBuilder
      tmpSQL.AppendLine("INSERT INTO dbo.tblReportTask (lngReportFields,lngChecklist,lngTask) ")
      tmpSQL.AppendLine(" VALUES ")
      tmpSQL.AppendLine("(@FIELD_ID, @CHECK_ID , @TASK) ")
      Using tmpCMD As New SqlCommand(tmpSQL.ToString, tmpCONN)
        tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIELD_ID", fieldID)
        tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIELD_ID", chk.cl_id)
        tmpCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FIELD_ID", chk.ts_id)
        tmpCMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End Using
    Next
  End Using
```

Comment: looks promising ... i will try this